# Insert some PHP/HTML mix inside of a PHP variable

Tags: php

I am trying to insert some PHP/HTML mix inside of a PHP variable.

`$media = '<br>'date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime( $key['date'] ))'<br>';`

But it doesn't work whatever i try. Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How am i supposed to ask any other way that i did. It's a clear question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to mix variables in php you must use `.`(dot). for your question. you must do it like this:

```
$media = '<br>'.date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime( $key['date'] )).'<br>';
```

Comment: Thanks so much ttrasn. I knew i had to use the dots, but i put them in the wrong places i guess. I'm no professional coder and have a night straight behind me, i'm done and i need sleep, that's probably why my brain don't function. I appreciate your help a lot. have a good day!